# SQL Server - Calculate total and filtered value

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-field

I've the following dataset:

```
Machine Type Value
1        A  11
1        B  32
2        A  23
3        A  1
4        B  23
4        B  31
5        B  56
6        A  12
```

And I want to the following calculation:

```
SELECT COUNT(WHERE TYPE = A) / COUNT(TOTAL)
FROM....
```

Which is the best way to do it? Is using With like:

```
DECLARE @CNT INT
SET @CNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset)
SELECT COUNT(*)/CNT
FROM dataset
WHERE TYPE = A
```

But if I have a big query repeating the same query for this calculations puts SQL to slow... Anyone can give a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using conditional aggregation: summing 1.0 will give you a percentage that isn't converted to an `int` of 0 or 1.

```
select sum(case when type='a' then 1.0 else 0 end)/count(*)
from t
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/GXN95560

```
create table t (Machine int, Type char(1), Value int)
insert into t values
 (1,'A',11)
,(1,'B',32)
,(2,'A',23)
,(3,'A',1 )
,(4,'B',23)
,(4,'B',31)
,(5,'B',56)
,(6,'A',12)

select sum(case when type='a' then 1.0 else 0 end)/count(*)
from t
```

returns: 0.500000

```
SELECT COUNT(case when TYPE = 'a' then 1 end) / COUNT(*)
FROM t
```

returns: 0

Answer (score 2):

Use a `case` expression to do conditional counting.

(When `type <> a`, the `case` will return null. `count()` doesn't count nulls.)

```
SELECT COUNT(case when TYPE = A then 1 end) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)
FROM dataset
```

**EDIT:**

Inspired by the other answers I decided to run some performance tests. The table tx used here has 10's of millions of rows. The column c2 is indexed, and has some hundred different values randomly placed all over the table.

Query 1:

```
select count(case when c2 = 'A' then 1 end) * 1.0 / count(*) from tx;

Direct I/O count      :      83067
Buffered I/O count    :          0
Page faults           :          3
CPU time     (seconds):      77.18
Elapsed time (seconds):      77.17
```

Query 2:

```
select avg(case when c2 = 'A' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) from tx;

Direct I/O count      :      83067
Buffered I/O count    :          0
Page faults           :          0
CPU time     (seconds):      84.90
Elapsed time (seconds):      84.90
```

Query 3:

```
select (select count(*) from tx where c2 = 'A') * 1.0 /
          (select count(*) from tx)
from onerow_table;

Direct I/O count      :      86204
Buffered I/O count    :          0
Page faults           :          2
CPU time     (seconds):       3.45
Elapsed time (seconds):       3.45
```

PS. Not run on MS SQL Server.

Comment: maybe `COUNT(case when TYPE = A then 1 end)` is actually counting the total number values come from column 1 or A or B, which does not exist in the target table, maybe use `SUM` to replace your first `COUNT`?

Comment: @LONG the COUNT is fine. However since it is integer divided with integer, this will always return 0 or 1 in case all types are A. Can be fixed by replacing 1 with 1.0

Comment: Oh, I see. for the `/` operation, I think that is the issue, too ;)

Comment: Some dbms need `* 1.0` to return decimal result, others don't... Added that part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little trick that Gordon demonstrated a couple of weeks ago. (can't seem to find the link)

```
Declare @YourTable table (Machine int, Type char(1), Value int)
insert into @YourTable values
 (1,'A',11)
,(1,'B',32)
,(2,'A',23)
,(3,'A',1 )
,(4,'B',23)
,(4,'B',31)
,(5,'B',56)
,(6,'A',12)

select avg(case when type='a' then 1.0 else 0 end)
from @YourTable
```

Returns

```
0.500000
```

Comment: Obviously I think this is the best solution ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just love the elegance.  Ashamed it never it never even dawned on me before.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
cast((sum(case when Type='A' then 1 else 0 end)) as float)/cast(Count(Type)) as float)
from dataset
```